# In dojo, How to get the input data from TextArea after submitting

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

```
var textarea = new dijit.form.Textarea({
    name: "myarea",
    rows: "14",
    cols: "50",
    style: "width:auto;"
  }, "myarea");
  textarea.set("value", "Text here ");
})
```

How to get the input data from TextArea after submitting.

I need to get all that data into a var.

Answer (score 0):

Textarea is a html node, so you can get the data using innerHTML on the textarea node (dijitTextArea.containerNode.innerHTML ? don't remember exactly, but it is something like that)

Comment: I did not get you. added way I created textarea

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly? your textarea is in a form? you are submitting your form and want to get the value of the textarea after submitting the form?

var textareaValue = textarea.get("value");
var textareaVal = textarea.conatainerNode.innerHTML; // should be the same

you could connet on form submission and get these if needed?

Comment: I am new bee to JavaScript and Dojo, I have a text area and one button and need to get the Input from user and parse it.